# Installing JavaScript Plasmoids in KDE 5

Tags: kde, kde5, plasma5, javascript

For the last year, I have been a happy user of KDE Plasma 5. KDE widgets, however, make me miss more directly programmable systems such as [conky](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/conky). Setting up an ad-hoc monitor for anything that needs monitoring at a given moment is not an easy task with KDE Plasma 5, whereas it is a matter of throwing together a shell script and adding a line to `~/.conkyrc`.

I understand that to expect conky's extensibility of KDE Plasma 5 would be to misunderstand the project's priorities. Nevertheless, KDE Plasma 4 appears to have [JavaScript bindings](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/PlasmaDesktopScripting#ECMA_Script_Interaction_With_Plasma_Shells), which would be much more suitable for ad-hoc desktop scripting compared to the primary Qt C++ API. The [kdeexamples Git repository](https://cgit.kde.org/kdeexamples.git) even contains a number of [example plasmoids written in JavaScript](https://cgit.kde.org/kdeexamples.git/tree/plasma/javascript/plasmoids). However, when I download the Git repository and install an arbitrary example widget:

```
$ git clone git://anongit.kde.org/kdeexamples.git
$ kdeexamples/plasma/javascript/plasmoids
$ (cd mediaplayer/; zip ../mediaplayer *)
$ plasmapkg -i mediaplayer.zip 
Successfully installed /home/witiko/kdeexamples/plasma/javascript/plasmoids/mediaplayer.zip
```

the widget never appears in the „Add Widget“ menu regardless of whether or not I restart Plasma:

```
$ killall plasmashell; kstart plasmashell
```

I am guessing that either things changed between KDE Plasma 4 and 5, or that I am doing something wrong. I will be grateful for pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kpackagetool5 -i this.plasmoid

is enough to get a proper plasmoid available to place, say on desktop.

try it with a known working one such as the steam punk clock: https://store.kde.org/p/1002162